# ¿Cómo se puede calcular el tiempo en minutos de un histórico de estados sin orden?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-12c

Tengo una tabla histórica donde se registran los cambios de estado de una solicitud, el estado inicial es SOLICITADA, los estados pueden cambiar varias veces al mismo estado, los estados no tienen un orden, en caso de que no exista un cambio de estado se debe calcular el tiempo transcurrido con la hora actual.

¿Cómo podría calcular el tiempo en minutos que transcurrió en el cambio de estado en su **primera aparición** en una tabla de histórico en Oracle 12c?

Histórico de una solicitud:

| # | CODIGO HISTORICO | ESTADO | FECHA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 196944 | SOLICITADA | 02/08/2023 15:40 |
| 2 | 197064 | CREADA | 02/08/2023 15:49 |
| 3 | 197065 | CREADA | 02/08/2023 15:50 |
| 4 | 197066 | SOLICITADA | 02/08/2023 15:51 |
| 5 | 197067 | CREADA | 02/08/2023 18:05 |
| 6 | 197069 | COMPLETADA | 02/08/2023 18:13 |

Se espera el siguiente resultado:
-SOLICITADA: 9 min (diferencia de minutos de fila 1 y 2)
-CREADA: 2 min (diferencia de minutos de fila 2 y 4)
-COMPLETADA: Dinámico (diferencia de minuto de fila 6 y hora actual)
-OtroEstado: 0

**SOLUCION**

Gracias a la ayuda recibida, la solución encontrada es la siguiente:

```sql
 
select  
    resultado.NumeroCaso,
    resultado.Estado,  
    trunc((coalesce(resultado.fechaFin_Estado, SYSDATE) - resultado.fechaInicio_estado) * 24 * 60)  DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS,    
    resultado.fechaInicio_estado ,
    resultado.fechaFin_Estado     
from (
select 
    auxiliar.Estado,
    auxiliar.NumeroCaso,
    auxiliar.fechaInicio_estado, 
    (select  
     min(fecha)fecha   
    from HistoricoEstado temp2 
    where  temp2.NumeroCaso=auxiliar.NumeroCaso and  Estado != 'SOLICITADA' 
    and temp2.fecha>auxiliar.fechaInicio_estado  and rownum <=1
    )fechaFin_Estado
 from (
    select 
        temp1.Estado,
        temp1.NumeroCaso,
        min(fecha) fechaInicio_estado
    from HistoricoEstado temp1 
    where Estado='SOLICITADA'
    group by temp1.NumeroCaso,temp1.Estado
)auxiliar
 
UNION ALL
 
select 
    auxiliar.Estado,
    auxiliar.NumeroCaso,
    auxiliar.fechaInicio_estado, 
    (select  
     fecha   
    from HistoricoEstado temp2 
    where  temp2.NumeroCaso=auxiliar.NumeroCaso and  Estado !='CREADA' 
    and temp2.fecha>auxiliar.fechaInicio_estado and rownum <=1
    )fechaFin_Estado
 from (
    select 
        temp1.Estado,
        temp1.NumeroCaso,
        min(fecha) fechaInicio_estado
    from HistoricoEstado temp1 
    where Estado='CREADA'
    group by temp1.NumeroCaso,temp1.Estado
)auxiliar
UNION ALL
select 
    auxiliar.Estado,
    auxiliar.NumeroCaso,
    auxiliar.fechaInicio_estado, 
    (select  
     fecha   
    from HistoricoEstado temp2 
    where  temp2.NumeroCaso=auxiliar.NumeroCaso and  Estado !='COMPLETADA' 
    and temp2.fecha>auxiliar.fechaInicio_estado and rownum <=1
    )fechaFin_Estado
 from (
    select 
        temp1.Estado,
        temp1.NumeroCaso,
        min(fecha) fechaInicio_estado
    from HistoricoEstado temp1 
    where Estado='COMPLETADA'
    group by temp1.NumeroCaso,temp1.Estado
)auxiliar 
) resultado;
```

Comment: No olvides colocar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y la estructura de la tabla en cuestión, _como texto, con formato_.

Comment: ¿La columna `CODIGO HISTORICO` es un consecutivo o en tu ejemplo todos deberían ser iguales? Si es un consecutivo, supongo que hay un error en el valor de la fila 6 y además se necesita una columna por la cual agrupar las filas que se tomarán para definir los cambios de estado. ¿Por qué se toma en cuenta el cambio de creada a solicitada pero no el segundo cambio de solicitada a creada?

Comment: @LuisCazares corregí el error de la fila 6, el "CODIGO HISTORICO" no se repite y va incrementando. Sobre la consulta, aclaro que el estado inicial es siempre SOLICITADA, el cliente definió solo considerar el tiempo del cambio de estado en su 1ra aparición en el histórico.

Comment: ¿Y como agrupas la solicitud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He preparado un ejemplo que asume que:

- Hay una cantidad manejable de filas en la tabla, es decir, no está *optimizado* para ejecutarse en grandes volúmenes de datos. De hecho, no tiene ningún tipo de optimización, pues solo demuestra una manera de hacerlo y no es código listo para producción.
- Asume que todo se basa en la hora de los estados, por lo que ignora la columna "CODIGO HISTORICO". Si esta columna es un consecutivo y está indexada, puede que sea mejor opción para realizar los cálculos (es de ver planes de ejecución, etc.).
- Asume que en la tabla hay cambios de estado para distintas transacciones,  documentos o casos y hay, por lo menos, otro campo que permita discriminar entre ellos. Le he llamado a ese hipotético campo `NumeroCaso` y se usa en el `where` para obtener los cambios de estado de un caso en particular.

En el ejemplo, lo que hago es valerme de un CTE para *preparar* los datos con dos cáluclos:

- Una numeración de filas que me permita identificar la primera vez que aparece un estado.
- Una sub-consulta que trae la fecha de cambio de estado que nos interesa y que, como se ve en el ejemplo, no necesariamente está en el siguiente registro. Esta sub-consulta devuelve `null` en el último cambio de estado.

Con esto en mano, en la consulta final, calculo la diferencia en minutos entre ambas fechas, usando la fecha actual si la de cambio de estado es `null` y me quedo solo con la primera aparición de cada estado.

Como siempre, el código dice más que mil palabras:

```
with
HistoricoEstadoNumerado as (
select   Estado
       , Fecha
       , (select min(Fecha)
            from HistoricoEstado h2
           where h2.NumeroCaso = h.NumeroCaso
             and h2.Estado != h.Estado
             and h2.Fecha > h.Fecha
         ) FechaCambioEstado
       , row_number() over (partition by Estado order by Fecha) NumeroAparicionEstado
  from HistoricoEstado h
 where NumeroCaso = 1
)
select   Estado
       , round((coalesce(FechaCambioEstado, SYSDATE) - Fecha) * 1440) MinutosEstado
  from HistoricoEstadoNumerado
 where NumeroAparicionEstado = 1    
 order by Fecha;
```

Con los datos de ejemplo, obtengo la salida:

| ESTADO | MINUTOSESTADO |
| --- | --- |
| SOLICITADA | 9 |
| CREADA | 2 |
| COMPLETADA | 1309 |

He dejado un script en [live Oracle](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/el3cggy4t0m78znkjha62y7f), dónde he desarrollado la solución.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ayudo bastante